# Markov Chains and Diophantine Equations

Tags: markov-chains, diophantine-equations

encountering the Markov equation, I was wondering if there is more of an intersection between Diophantine equations and Markov chains?

Comment: Could you be more specific with your question? What sort of intersection are you looking for? How much do you know about each topic? Have you noticed anything in particular which inspired you to ask this question?

Comment: @C-RAM , I am not really sure myself what i am trying to find. What inspired me to ask this is on the Markov equation where i learned that its solutions created a markov chain while having it being a Diophantine equation. For my knowledge, i know the basics of what each are.